# How to hide or remove column from data table or set it invisible using flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a screen as the below one:

[image: HomeScreen]

So I need now to remove the columns with name `Name` & `Value` and just keep the rows or even set the column visible, I tried to create `DataTable` without Column by removing them it gives me an error and conflicts, as it's gives me the below error:

```
'package:flutter/src/material/data_table.dart': Failed assertion: line 419 pos 15: 'columns != null': is not true.
```

So there's any way to remove this?

Here's a small part for my code:

```
DataTable(
                            columnSpacing: 83,
                            dataRowHeight: double.parse('20'),
                            columns: [
                              DataColumn(label: Text('Name')),
                              DataColumn(
                                  label: Row(
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  Text('Value'),
                                ],
                              )),
                            ],
                            rows: [
                              DataRow(cells: [
                                DataCell(Row(
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    Text('Sim operator'),
                                  ],
                                )),
                                DataCell(
                                  Text(simInfo.operator == null
                                      ? ' '
                                      : simInfo.operator),
                                ),
                              ]),
                              DataRow(cells: [
                                DataCell(Row(
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    Text('ICCID'),
                                  ],
                                )),
                                DataCell(
                                    Text(simInfo == null ? '' : simInfo.iccid)),
                              ]),
                            ],
                          ),
```

Comment: can't you use Text() or Text('Name', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)) ... silly but will this work?

Comment: Do you want to be able to hide all the DataTable (hiding all columns)?

Comment: @racr0x yes exactly I don't need any column in the DataTable I just need only rows

Comment: @VisakhVijayan good idea may be I can use `headingRowHeight: 0.0,` and make the text color with the same color of background but I need more smarter solution :D

Comment: You can always mock the table structure using a Row widget if the display is all you want to do with it.

Comment: @VisakhVijayan can get your idea :(

Comment: Use a row with two columns inside, representing your columns.

Comment: @racr0x huh yes exactly this is the smartest solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily change the Text('some data text', style: **TextStyle(color: Colors.transparent))**

But alternatively I will recommend you take a moment to understand the data and create a class that fits your data - model. In order you can take whatever data directly from the corresponding data - object. And display it wherever you want.

Otherwise you can use a Stack() widget. Syntax like a Column or Row // with children[] // and just put a container above it.

Comment: thanks a lot I think I solved by add the same height of row and make the columns as the rows and fill them with data normally :), thanks for your support

Answer (score 4):

if you want to don't show column title, set them as empty Text and set `headingRowHeight` property to 0 or another small number.

```
DataTable(
                            columnSpacing: 83,
                            headingRowHeight: 0,
                            dataRowHeight: double.parse('20'),
                            columns: [
                              DataColumn(label: Text('')),
                              DataColumn(label: Text('')),
                            ],
                            rows: [
                              ...
                            ],
                          ),
```

another way is use Table widget that you have much control on details
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Table-class.html

Answer (score 0):

You can do conditional rendering like this -
Wrap your DataColumn and the corresponding DataCell in an if condition.
if (your condition)...[DataColumn()],
if (your condition)...[DataCell()],

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).